# Sufficient condition for $k$-colorability

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

We know that a graph is $ 2 $-colorable iff it has no odd cycles. I am asked to generalize this statement to the following: a graph is $ k $-colorable if each vertex is in less than $ \binom{k}{2} $ distinct odd cycles.

I am having trouble with this proof: let's prove by induction on the size of the vertex set of $ G $. Clearly it is true if $ |V(G)| \leq k $. Suppose it is true for $ |V(G)| < n $, and let $ G' = G - \{ x \} $. Since removing a vertex does not create more cycles, we have that $ G' $ is $ k $-colorable. Now we have to show that we can color $ x $ without creating a conflict. But how to proceed? Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea in the last step you're having trouble with is essentially the same as the idea of "Kempe chains" in the proof of the five-color theorem.

If we're adding the vertex $x$ back in, and its neighbors don't already use all $k$ colors, then it's easy to color $x$: just give it a color that's not used by its neighbors.

If all $k$ colors are used on the neighbors of $x$, we may try the following algorithm:

1. Let Azure and Beige be any two of the colors.
2. Let $G_{AB}$ be the graph obtained by the following process:

   - Start with all neighbors of $x$ which are colored Azure.
   - Next, add on all neighbors of those vertices which are colored Beige.
   - Next, add on all neighbors of *those* vertices which are colored Azure.
   - Keep going until there are no more vertices to add.
3. Reverse the colors of $G_{AB}$: switch Azure to Beige and Beige to Azure.
4. Color $x$ Azure.

If all goes well, then in the new coloring, $x$ no longer has any neighbors colored Azure, all of them have been switched to Beige. So we are free to color $x$ Azure, and get a $k$-coloring of $G$.

The trouble is that $G_{AB}$ could eventually include some neighbors of $x$ which are colored Beige. If it does, then reversing the colors of $G_{AB}$ gets rid of all neighbors of $x$ colored Azure (turning them into Beige), but turns some of $x$'s Beige neighbors into Azure, so $x$ *still* has Azure neighbors, and there's no way to color $x$.

However, if that happens, then there is an Azure-Beige odd cycle containing $x$: a cycle that starts at $x$ and goes through $G_{AB}$, alternating Azure-Beige-Azure-Beige-...-Azure-Beige until it comes back to $x$.

By assumption, there are fewer than $\binom k2$ odd cycles through $x$. Well, there are $\binom k2$ pairs of colors we could have used in place of Azure and Beige. Therefore, there is a pair of colors that does not result in such a cycle, and our recoloring algorithm will work for that pair of colors.

Comment: Nice answer :) -- do you think there's a way tha tI could make my suggestion (from the comments) work? I've thought about it a lot (stopped me getting to sleep for a while last night! =P), but I couldn't quite think how to do it. You're clearly pretty au fait with the only graph theory shenanigans (at least from your SE activity!): can you see how it might work?

Comment: You cannot conclude from the fact that $\delta(G) \ge k$ alone that a vertex is contained in at least $\binom k2$ odd cycles. For one thing, you might have a very dense bipartite graph, and no vertex is contained in any odd cycles at all.

Comment: Very nice answer. Does it mean that we only need one vertex in less than $ \binom{k}{2} $ odd cycles, rather than requiring all vertices to be in less than $ \binom{k}{2} $ odd cycles?

Comment: You need the other vertices to have this property so that you can induct. (More precisely, you need every vertex with degree $\ge k$ to be in less than $\binom k2$ odd cycles.)

Comment: Ah, of course, just take complete bipartite graph with two classes of size $k$ to get no odd cycles at all =P -- I've removed my comments from the OP, since they're unhelpful.