# Each vertex of a graph $G$, lies in fewer than $n$ odd cycles, prove $G$ is $2(n+1)$-colorable.

Tags: graph-theory

Each vertex of a graph $G$, lies in fewer than $n$ odd cycles, prove $G$ is $2(n+1)$-colorable.

Comment: what is a queer cycle?

Comment: A [much stronger statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2520571/sufficient-condition-for-k-colorability) is true, though the proof of the linked question is trickier.

Answer (score 1):

Take some minimal set of edges $S$, such that after removing $S$ we have no odd cycles. Then each vertex is incident with at most $n$ edges from $S$, as each such edge has to belong to some odd cycle avoiding other edges from $S$ (by minimality).

Try to arrive to the solution from that.